# Limiting API in a while loop by sleeping?

Tags: php

I need to sleep in a while loop.

The API is limited to 300 request per minute.

Comment: Er, OK, then just call the function within your loop? Any problem with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sleep() is not a reliable way to limit the use of a rate limited api (you should be using usleep() anyway). I take it you are calling an external API that is limited to 300 requests per minute? Also, the point of rate limiting is that you don't overload the API. Calling it 300 times in the first 10 seconds defeats the point of the rate limit and is likely to get your system banned.

In this scenario you should be calling the API at most once every 200 miliseconds (60 seconds / 300)

I would use something like (thank you @Codler for the code in your answer that I based this on)

```
$time1 = microtime(true);

while(true) {

    callTheAPI();

    $time2 = microtime(true);

    if (($time2 - $time1) * 1000 >= 200) {
        $time1 = $time2;
    } else {
        // usleep to make up for the 200 miliseconds 
        $sleep = ($time2 - $time1) * 1000;
        usleep($sleep);
        $time1 = microtime(true);
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while(myCondition)
{
  // request code
  $sleepTime = 5; /*time in seconds, find its optimum value so that you can use the API to its maximum */

  sleep($sleepTime);
}
```

Comment: sleep() only allows seconds, that means it can only process 60 requests a minute, much bellow the max allowed.

Comment: then use usleep which allows microseconds and hence more control :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$time = microtime(true);
$i = 0;
while(true) {
    doSomething();
    $i++;
    if ($i >= 300) {
        $i = 0;

        // if it hasn't reached 60 seconds yet, sleep. 
        $sleep = microtime(true) - $time;
        if ($sleep < 60) {
            sleep(60 - $sleep);
        }
        $time = microtime(true);
    } 
}
?>
```